# Delete duplicate rows (searched and tried what is on here already)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've for a day or two tried to remove a couple of duplicate database rows that appeared in my system after a minor fail on my end, I've tried most (if not all) methods I've been able to find on Stackoverflow so far. I've had several of those methods work flawlessly previously on the same mariadb and mysql as I've tried to delete now.

This is my table structure.

ID | date | experience | characterid

ID is the unique identifier (aka Auto incremeting), each character ID should have only ONE entry per date, and that's what's been duplicated. Some characterids have 5-7 entries per date, identical dates (I've checked).

I've tried the following queries to remove them which have worked in the past for similar issues I've had.

```
DELETE n1 FROM experiencehistory n1, experiencehistory n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.date = n2.date AND n1.characterid = n2.characterid
```

aswell as

```
DELETE experiencehistory FROM experiencehistory
```

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(id) as RowId, characterid, date
   FROM experiencehistory 
   GROUP BY characterid, date
) as KeepRows ON
   experiencehistory.id = KeepRows.RowId
WHERE
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL

Both produce no results in console and through PHPMyadmin I get this error;

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected token. (near "experiencehistory" at position 7)
```

Any suggestions on what I could do to resolve this or if I did something wrong with these methods  I've tried primarily?

Serverversion: 10.1.13-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Thankful for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way  (delete all id != for min(id)  group by characterid, date

```
DELETE FROM experiencehistory
where (id, characterid, date) not in 
      ( select x_id, characterid , x_date from  ( select  min(x.id) as x_id
                  , x.characterid as x_characterid 
                 , x.date  as x_date
          from  experiencehistory  as x group by x.characterid, x.date ) t );
```

Comment: I do quite like this idea, however somewhere along the line I get a error spat at me. Tried removing/adding parenthases but couldn't quite figure out this error, perhaps you've run across something similar?
>>>
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from experiencehistory group by characterid, date) )' at line 2

>> Also added server verison in the first post.

Comment: It did seem to work just fine when running the updated post the first time except for it timing out (I hadn't considered that the table in question contains over a million rows). However, on second run (after I had increased the max run time to 24 hours) I get this #1093 - Table 'experiencehistory' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data 

At first I thought, hey maybe it's because all duplicates were deleted but that was not the case. Really annoying!

Comment: I am still getting the same error, dang this is a tricky thing to achieve!